# C - forward declare and use struct not pointer

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to forward declare struct_A and use it within `struct_B` not as a pointer but as a structure.
Within `struct_B`, I make reference to `struct_B`.

I can't seem to get it right - help?
Here's my **code**:

```
struct type_A_t;
typedef struct type_A_t type_A_t;

typedef struct type_B_t {
    type_A_t a;
};

struct  type_A_t{
    void (*cb)(type_B_t *b1);
    void (*cb)(type_B_t *b2);
};
```

The error I get is:

> error: field 'type_A_t' has incomplete type

Comment: another problem is that `type_B_t` is not defined

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. But in your example, since `type_A_t` only needs to know about pointers to `type_B_t`, why not switch it around like this?

```
typedef struct type_B_t type_B_t;
typedef struct type_A_t type_A_t;

struct  type_A_t {
    void(*cb)(type_B_t *b1);
    void(*cb)(type_B_t *b2);
};
typedef struct type_B_t {
    type_A_t a;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to get it right - help?

Because it cannot be done.

The compiler doesn't know the size of that struct.

A forward declaration is enough for pointers though:

```
typedef struct type_B_t {
    type_A_t a;  // error
    type_A_t* a; // OK
};
```

Of course, if in your real code, you can switch the order, as @Blaze's answer mention, then do that.

Comment: This is a C only question, there are no references.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. To use a type as a member, the type's size must be known, so it must be fully defined. Otherwise, `sizeof(struct type_B_t)` would be unknown after its definition, which makes no sense.